# jquery slide animation not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am using AngularJS and JQuery in my project.

I have a login page which contains navigation bar, logo and a simple login form. I am using AngularJS-route to navigatet trough pages.

I'm trying to use JQuery animate to make some animations when the page is loaded.

I'm using JQuery slideDown function to make the logo slowly fade in form the top, and also fade in function for the login card.

I included all the necessary libraries(jquery, jquery animate in my main html page)

Here is my Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#logo').slideDown(1000);
        $("#login-card").fadeIn(1000);       
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that when I load the login page(by typing the address into the address bar or by refreshing the page) I don't see the animation, The logo just pops up after one second.

However, when I use the navigation bar and click on the sign link(which should bring me to the login page), I see the logo slideDown animation just fine.

Here is my whole login.html:

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#logo').slideDown(1000);
        $("#login-card").fadeIn(1000);       
    });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 menu" ng-controller="modeController" ng-show="$root.signingMode != 'api'">
            <ul class="navigation-bar">
                <li class="nav-bar-item" ng-class="{'active': mode === '/sign'}" ng-click="changeMode('/sign')"><a href="">Sign</a></li>
                <li class="nav-bar-item" ng-class="{'active': mode === '/verify'}" ng-click="changeMode('/verify')"><a href="">Verify</a></li>          
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <!-- <img class="logo-img" src="images/logo.png"> -->
            <div class="logo" id="logo" style="display: none">
                <img class="logo-img" src="http://placehold.it/100x100/0bf?text=Logo">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="row">
        <div class="login-card" id="login-card" style="display: none">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1>Log-in</h1><br>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username">
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
                    <input type="submit" name="login" class="login login-submit" value="login" ng-click="login()">
                    <span id="login-error-msg" class="login-error" ng-show="displayError">*Wrong Username/Password</span>
                    <!-- <span id="login-error-msg" class="login-error" ng-style="errorMsg">*Wrong Username/Password</span> -->
                    <!-- <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button> -->
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

  <!-- <div class="login-help">
    <a href="#">Register</a> • <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
</div> -->
</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** If I change slideDown to fadeIn everything works fine.

**EDIT2:** I tried to create a plunker with almost the almost exact same code, and it is working. The image I am using in plunker is actually bigger than my logo.
Here is the plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/VQWCMvDpttwlYEwRUqwM?p=preview

**EDIT3:** I forgot to save the plunker, sorry. Now, the plunker link is wokring.

And you can see the exact same behaviour I am getting on my page, the first time the page is loaded there is no animation, the logo just pops up. Next time it's fine.

Comment: Your just out of luck

Comment: What is that supposed to mean? And, why the downvote?

Comment: I think your out of luck because your issue cannot be replicated - as it currently stands.

Comment: if using $(document).load(function(){ instead ready maybe work. Let me know, cheers.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sould I paste more code? I have two more pages that may be relevant: my main index.html which loads the view using ng-view and js file which contains angular-route config.

Comment: @Roy I tried to use $(document).load(function(), but now the elements aren't loading at all

Comment: @user3362334 what Roy meant is probably `$(window).load(function(){` with the explanation that your logo image is too big to load and your animation starts before the logo is actually fully loaded - making it actually a good suggestion.

Comment: That's correct Roko.

Comment: I tried $(window).load(function(){ with the same result(the elements not showing up at all)

Comment: I tried $(window).on('load', function() {, but also not showing up

Comment: try setting css height on your logo class.

Answer (score 1):

> As per my understanding you want to chain your events like you want to
>   slide down #logo and then want to fadein #login-card. You can do like
>   below:

========================================================================

```
$('#logo').slideDown(1000, function(){$('#login-card').fadeIn(1000);});
```

You can see working example on Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Vqy645WChwcQmdJtSQWF?p=preview

you can change this on click of link also.